# Do you collect $200 in Monopoly if you don't ask for it?

Tags: monopoly

If a player passes Go but doesn't ask for their money and the next player plays, does the first player still get their money if they ask only after the next round is played? I could not find this in the Monopoly rules.

Comment: To what end? The point of a game is to be fun, and the rules are there to facilitate that. How does this rule increase the enjoyability of the game, for anyone? The person who missed out on $200 is pissed off about losing $200, and everyone else's game experience is diminished by making the game unjustly easier for them.

Comment: Ahhh, "house rules". People have lost friends over less. You need to use a little philosophy here... There's worse things at steak than £200 of monopoly money. So agree to the house rules BUT maintain them rigidly when the house-rule-er breaks their own rules. Be consistent and balanced, then you've got a workable game.

Comment: If you don't ask for your direct deposit does your employer still pay you?

Comment: @AJFaraday Workable is not the same as fun.

Comment: @jpmc26 A game where any one player decides to dispute, and continue disputing, some minor point in the rules is never fun. Conversations where someone blames a minor point for losing a game are not fun. (Neither are ones where a player gloats continually). A good game may not be strictly correct, but will be amiable.

Comment: @AJFaraday If you are uncomfortable with the rules, you need not play the game. Choose a different game, or find something else to do. *Starting* a game with rules you don't want to play by is the first mistake there. You *will* be unhappy if they bite you, and your host will be unhappy if you spitefully turn the rule against them. Just say no to bad games. =)

Comment: @jpmc26 or, you know, play with people you actually like, and trust, and don't play for death or glory... I suppose this discussion belongs in the philosophy SE, really.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica If you look at the history of the game monopoly, the point of the game actually WASN'T to be fun. This game was invented as a teaching tool to teach anti-monopolist ideas, to teach how dangerous monopolies were to society at large, and to that end only the person winning would have fun.

Answer (score 95):

**Yes, you still collect $200.**

From the [rulebook](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/monins.pdf):

> Each time a player’s token lands on or passes over GO,
>   whether by throwing the dice or drawing a card, the Banker pays
>   him/her a $200 salary.

No mention of the player "asking" for the money or anything. It says the Banker pays him, so the Banker pays him.

Comment: Monopoly suffers from many, many, house-rules – in other words, rules that people decide to use despite the fact they aren't the ones written down. I've heard of this being one such house rule. In my opinion, this house rule doesn't improve the game – it just allows people to be smug at other people's discomfort even more…

Comment: To be clear, this says that it is the Banker's responsibility to ensure that the player is paid. If the Banker is deliberately withholding money because the player didn't ask for it, they are the ones breaking the rules (unless the table has agreed to a house rule that says otherwise).

Comment: @BillMichell Suffers is the perfect word for it. "It's so lame without money in the middle. You run out so fast." Three hours later "Wow this game sucks it takes forever..."

Comment: The only time I'm aware of where a player is required to ask for the money is when demanding rent because another player lands on owned property.  The rules specifically state that the player does need to catch the opportunity before the potentially-owing player rolls the dice.  When I played, my parents enforced the rule that a player cannot just roll dice twice quickly (due to rolling doubles) without giving the property-owner a fair chance to notice and request the rent, but if all (remaining) other player(s) took a turn (including the property owner), that was plenty of opportunity.

Comment: @BillMichell nah it suffers from people that only wants to win even if it means to ruin the fun. "You forget to ask, I do not pay you", "I stole in the bank ? You didn't see me".

Comment: @TOOGAM I believe you are mistaken; the property owner has until the _next_ player rolls the dice--it doesn't have to go all the way around, and doubles wouldn't matter as it's still the same person who owes the rent.  "The owner may not collect the rent if he/she fails to ask for it before
the second player following throws the dice."  https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/monins.pdf

Comment: @thumbtackthief : Indeed, it looks like that was a house rule that snuck into my understanding.  Thank you for keeping me on the straight and narrow.  As phrased, there's no reason that a person has to hurry to yell before the active player throws dice another time (due to doubles).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's an "accounting" transaction.

Another poster pointed out that the "banker" is supposed to pay the player. Let's say the banker doesn't. (There are only two players, and they're using "honor system" for "banking" transactions.)

The player is "entitled" to his $200 for passing go, and the honor system permits him to take it. In "real life," people sometimes "forget" or delay in collecting their paychecks, but the pay is still real.

Another example: The rules say that there are 32 houses and 12 hotels. Some of them are missing from the set. You use coins or other tokens to make up the difference, so that the game plays fairly. On the other hand, if a 33rd house somehow got mixed in from another set, you should play without it.

Answer (score -2):

thus is what Wikibooks says under “general play” rules for Monopoly...
If the player lands on or passes Go in the course of his or her turn, he or she receives $200 from the Bank. A player has until the beginning of his or her next turn to collect this money. ...There you go!

Comment: There is no mention of not getting it if you miss it after your next turn starts.

Comment: Hasbro, not Wikipedia, is the final arbiter on questions of rules...